# How to write/pipe to a virtual webcam created by V4L2loopback module?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, v4l2, v4l2loopback

I have written an application which reads from a webcam and processes the frames using OpenCV on linux.

Now I want to pipe the output of my application to a virtual webcam that has been created by the V4L2loopback module so other applications are able to read it.

I have written the application using C.

How do I approach doing this?

Comment: There's nothing about OpenCV specifically here. Any app like [this](http://www.senstic.com/iphone/aircam/aircam.aspx) (never used, googled it) can gel well with OpenCV.

Comment: Sorry what did you mean by the app you liked to can 'gel' with opencv? My question is how to use V4L2Loopback module to create a virtual webacam and write frames to it using my application so other applications can use the virtual video device to view the frames that I have written to it. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found an answer in the old V4L2loopback module's page on Google code.

http://code.google.com/p/v4l2loopback/source/browse/test.c

newer link: https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/blob/master/examples/test.c

This has helped me so far just to write to the device.

Comment: btw, v4l2loopback is now developed at [github](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) and no longer at googlecode.

Comment: @user447519 could you provide a little code snippet? Unfortunately I was not able to make it work with the links above. My output on VLC remains black. Please see my post for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508743/unable-to-route-webcam-video-to-virtual-video-device-on-linux-via-opencv

Comment: This amounts to a link-only answer. If the author doesn't fix within a reasonable time-frame, someone else please add a new answer and flag this one for deletion.